# Number of strings that start and end with the same letter or are palindromes or contain vowels only

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In this question, we consider strings consisting of 26 characters, with each character being a uppercase letter. Determine the number of such strings that
>  
>   (a) start and end with the same letter, or
>  
>   (b) are palindromes, or
>  
>   (c) contain vowels only

For this problem, I approached each scenario a, b, c separately. I then joined the 3 with an OR to satisfy the question in the final answer.

a. $26$ characters, if the last letter must be the same as the first, we really only have $25$ characters to choose from, so part a = $26^ {25}$

b. $26$ characters, but if it is a palindrome, the length is cut in half, giving us $26^{13}$.

c. If the characters are vowels only, there are only A E I O U, $5$ characters to choose from. And we have a full 26 characters to pick. $26^{5}$

The three value then gets OR'd together

$26^ {25}$ OR $26^{13}$ OR $26^{5}$

Is what I did correct? I'm working from practice problems and am not given an answer key so it's hard to really practice when I don't know if I'm doing it right or wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Is that three separate questions? Or is it a single question meaning to find the number of all strings such that each such string satisfies at least one of the three conditions? In the latter case, your answer makes no sense because "OR" is an operation on statements (and propositions), but it's **NOT** an operation on numbers. For example: we understand what "5+3" means and can compute it; but what do you think "5 OR 3" could possibly mean and what is it equal to? Hint: inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: I think the three separate calculations are correct. For the "or" you start by adding those counts. But then you must correct for the fact that some strings will be counted multiple times, in two or three of the categories. Have you studied inclusion-exclusion counting?

Comment: @EthanBolker, the $26^5$ is not correct. It should be $5^{26}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Right thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is

$$26^{25}+5^{26}-5^{25}$$

There are two key steps in getting the answer.  First, condition (b) is irrelevant: palindromes necessarily start and end with the same letter, so they've already been accounted for under condition (a).  Second is the inclusion-exclusion principle applied to conditions (a) and (c):  After adding together the counts for each condition separately, you subtract the count of their intersection, namely the number of vowel strings that begin and end with the same vowel.

The OP mistakenly got $26^5$ instead of $5^{26}$ for condition (c); $26^5$ counts the number of $5$-character strings, with each character being *any* letter of the alphabet. (When forming a string of vowels, there are $5$ choices for the first character, $5$ for the second, and so forth, for a total of $5\times5\times\cdots\times5$.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I understand that |AuB| = |A| + |B| - |AnB|. I was wondering how you came to get $-5^{25}$.

Comment: @user1692517, there is a total of $25$ vowel choices:  one for the first and last characters (which must match) and one each for the $24$ middle characters.

Comment: Can I ask a question? So you mean that scenario (b) is not necessary to consider?

Comment: @kimiTanaka, that's correct.  The question is, in effect, asking for the number of objects in the union of three sets, but one of the sets is a subset of another.

Comment: Thanks, if the question is without “or” you need to consider the scenario (b). Otherwise, scenario (a) already contains (b).

Comment: @kimiTanaka, that's right, the "or"s make the problem into a single question about a union of sets. Without the "or"s it'd be three separate questions (unless you interpreted it as a single question with tacit "and"s, in which case the answer would simply be $5^{13}$, because you'd just be counting palindromes consisting of vowels).

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks a lot, I got it. Yes, if I tacitly filled “and” in between them, there would be only vowels palindrome. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Let me consider that you pick up the first letter is same and the last letter is automatically the same. therefore  $26^{25}$

(b) I think this one is complicated to explain, you need to consider 1 same numbers pair and other 24 letters are the same, 2 pairs of the same numbers and different to other pairs and the rest of 22 letters are the same... 13 pairs of the same numbers and different from other pairs. therefore  $26P1 + 26P2 + 26P3  + 26P4 + 26P5 + 26P6 + 26P7 + 26P8 + 26P9 + 26P10 + 26P11 + 26P12 + 26P13$.

(c) You have only vowels in 26 letters of a string. So, you should consider only vowels for 26 letters in a row. Therefore,

$5^{26}$

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I messed up part C.

Comment: @user1692517  Barry Cipra’s answer is correct.Sorry I messed (b) up too. If you consider the only scenario(b), it would be $26^{13}$ as you know.